# Windows authentication in connection string (ASP .Net Application)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, iis, connection-string

I had a common windows account for App and DB servers say ApplicationAdmin. now i want to set both servers with different windows account. i created two windows account on same domain  ApplicationAPP and ApplicationDB for both servers and activeted on respective servers.

My Application is using windows authentication in connection string. When i am disabling ApplicationAdmin account from sql server on DB server i am getting error " Login failed for user 'Domain\ApplicationAdmin'. Reason: The account is disabled".

Due to some reason i can't delete old ApplicationAdmin Account from domain. How can we change default windows authentication which a connection string takes it self. I want that query string  takes windows authentication as Domain\ApplicationAPP which i have added to sql server at DB server.

In sort i have two active windows account on app server and my connection string taking old authentication but i required it to take newly configured user's authentication.

Comment: What account your "application" runs under? I strongly suspect it is still running under "ApplicationAdmin" even if you claim otherwise.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov : even if i remove ApplicationAdmin user from the server i am getting the same error.. how to configure/change account for application...?